# Post content stays the same but permalink changes ?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, query

This is really weird. I made a posttype ' mediagallery ' via the plugin Types fields.
I simply want to load the post content and switch the posts with a next & prev button in de sidebar.

The post content loads correct. But when i go to the next or prev post, the content stays the same. But only the permalink does changes. All posts are refering to the same post?

This is the code example:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post_type' => 'Mediagallery' );
query_posts($args);
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>

<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php echo  apply_filters( 'the_content'  ,  types_render_field('mediaid')); ?>


<?php endwhile; ?> 
<?php else : ?> <?php endif; ?> <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

When i change post_per_page to 2 they correctly show up both, so the post it there but it only shows one (the newest post), i tried different things But somehow i can only show the newest and all posts are loading that content ?

i hope someone can help me,

Greetz

Answer (score 0):

> I ... want to ... switch the posts with a next & prev button in [a] sidebar.
>
> But only the permalink ... changes.

You do not say what the permalink is changing to. It sounds like you might be talking about pagination in a custom loop. Your query ignores the page number and always returns page 1.

I don't know how to safely use [query_posts()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts#answer-1755). Here is a solution using the [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) object. First it gets the current page number and then it adds that number to the query. (I removed the `else` and the `if` clause since they were not doing anything and stopped all that jumping in and out of PHP.)

```
$page_number = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$media_gallery = new WP_Query( array(
    'paged'          => $page_number,
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type'      => 'Mediagallery',
) );

while ( $media_gallery->have_posts() ) {
    $media_gallery->the_post();

    printf( '<h1>%s</h1>', get_the_title() );
    echo apply_filters( 'the_content', types_render_field('mediaid') );
}

wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response man, however the result is the same.. For example, i have a post with the permalink . http://racing:8888/mediagallery/supercup-600/ & one with http://racing:8888/mediagallery/supercup-1000/. & http://racing:8888/mediagallery/test/ They all link to the most recent post(supercup 600). When i use the next/prev link or i straight use the permalink they all go to supercup 600. But with the permalink changed to for example supercup 1000. Strangely it doens't seem to find the next post or load the correct content of that post..

Comment: You didn't give the urls up top and you still haven't explained the logic behind which posts should appear on each page, so I had to assume what you were doing. Add this information to the original question (using the Edit link) with an explanation of which posts you expect to have on the supercup-1000 page and which posts you expect on the test page, etc.